# minikube intermittent ErrImageNeverPull

Tags: minikube

When I run minikube, I get ErrImageNeverPull intermittently. I am not sure why, so I ask. First of all, I set `imagePullPolicy: Never` to this (writes the internal image), and I verified that everything works fine. However, sometimes phpmyadmin is ErrImageNeverPull, wordpress is ErrImageNeverPull, and so on. The environment is running on a laptop Mac Catalina.

I don't know the exact reason, but what is the reason to infer?

```sh
kubectl logs wordpress-deployment-5545dcd6f5-h6mfx
Error from server (BadRequest): container "wordpress" in pod "wordpress-deployment-5545dcd6f5-h6mfx" is waiting to start: ErrImageNeverPull
```

```sh
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------             ----                   ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling   9m14s (x2 over 9m14s)  default-scheduler  persistentvolumeclaim "wordpress-pv-claim" not found
  Normal   Scheduled          9m11s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/wordpress-deployment-5545dcd6f5-h6mfx to minikube
  Warning  Failed             6m55s (x13 over 9m8s)  kubelet, minikube  Error: ErrImageNeverPull
  Warning  ErrImageNeverPull  4m8s (x26 over 9m8s)   kubelet, minikube  Container image "wordpress-dockerfile" is not present with pull policy of Never
```

Oh, of course, I also applied the following command.

```sh
# eval $(minikube docker-env)
eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)
```

Again, the shocking fact is that I have confirmed that all of these are working correctly and it happens intermittently.

[image]

Comment: Are you using a private repo? What is the minikube and kubernetes version?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I fixed the problem just before. The reason is that I ran it on a personal laptop, but the number of Pods created was probably so the laptop couldn't stand. When I ran it to the actual desktop, all 10 out of 10 ran fine without any errors. In actual ```minikube start```, I did not give a separate cpu or memory option, but it seems that the cause of the error was that the total usage was not considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem just before. The reason is that I ran it on a personal laptop, but the number of Pods created was probably so the laptop couldn't stand. When I ran it to the actual desktop, all 10 out of 10 ran fine without any errors. In actual `minikube start`, I did not give a separate cpu or memory option, but it seems that the cause of the error was that the total usage was not considered.